Fourier analysis of sine: magnitude result clarification
I want to calculate the Fourier transform of $sine(2 \pi 60 t)$ and I have difficulty understanding/calculating the magnitude result. It is already known that the only frequency on this sine function is at 60hz so this is what its expected to come out at the magnitude vs frequency plot. About the amplitude of magnitude: From theory I know that the magnitude should be $\frac{1}{2}$ of the amplitude $A = 1$ in this case, so magnitude should be $\frac{1}{2}$.
My solution attempt:
The Fourier transfer function is:
$ {F}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ e^{-j \omega t}dt $
Where $f(x)=sine(2 \pi 60 t +\phi_0)$ for this attempt.
$\Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}sine(2 \pi 60 t +\phi_0)\ e^{-j \omega t}dt $
Now, let us set $2 \pi 60 =\omega$ and $\phi_0 = 0$ since we do not care about the original engle, its 0.
$\Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}sine(\omega t)e^{-j \omega t}dt $
From Euler's formula and its variations, it is seen that $S_o sin(\omega t)=\frac{S_o}{2j}e^{j\omega t}-\frac{S_o}{2j}e^{-j\omega t}$ where $S_o=1$ in this case. So replacing $sine(\omega t)$ it will become:
$\Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg[ \frac{1}{2j}e^{j\omega t}-\frac{1}{2j}e^{-j\omega t} \bigg] e^{-j \omega t}dt $
$2j$ is common denominator so it can be written:
$\Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg[ \frac{e^{j\omega t} - e^{-j\omega t}}{2j}  \bigg] e^{-j \omega t}dt $
$\frac{1}{2j}$ can be left outside of integral:
$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2j} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg[ e^{j\omega t} - e^{-j\omega t}  \bigg] e^{-j \omega t}dt $
And then using distributive property:
$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2j} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j\omega t}e^{-j \omega t} - e^{-j\omega t}e^{-j \omega t}dt  $
Which will help better if the integral splits and is written as:
$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2j} \bigg[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{j\omega t})e^{-j \omega t} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{-j\omega t})e^{-j \omega t}dt\bigg]  $
Now, doesnt that look like the original Fourier tranfer function, with $f(x) = e^{j\omega t}$ for the first integral and $f(x) = e^{-j\omega t}$ for the second integral? So it will be:
$\Rightarrow {F}(\omega)= \frac{1}{2j} \bigg[ F\{e^{j\omega t}\} - F\{e^{-j\omega t} \} \bigg] $
and then, given the Fourier transform of $ F\{ e^{(j\omega t)} \} = 2\pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0) $ and
$ F\{ e^{(-j\omega t)} \} = 2\pi \delta (\omega +\omega_0) $ , we have:
$\Rightarrow {F}(\omega)= \frac{1}{2j} \bigg[ 2\pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0) - 2\pi \delta (\omega +\omega_0)  \bigg] $
Next, two modifications will be done at once. 1. the $2$'s cancel each other. 2. Its not desirable to leave the $j$ at the denominator so a multiplication with $j$ is done such as:
$\Rightarrow {F}(\omega)= \frac{1*j}{\cancel{2}j*j} \bigg[ \cancel{2}\pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0) - \cancel{2}\pi \delta (\omega +\omega_0)  \bigg] $
$j*j$ at the denominator becomes $j^{2}=-1$ so:
$\Rightarrow {F}(\omega)= -1j\bigg[ \pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0) - \pi \delta (\omega +\omega_0)  \bigg] $
$\Rightarrow {F}(\omega)= j\bigg[ \pi \delta (\omega +\omega_0)  -\pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0)\bigg] $
===================== End of solution attempt.
Because of $ F\{ e^{(j\omega t)} \} = 2\pi \delta (\omega -\omega_0) $ the expected $\frac{1}{2}$ of my amplitude is gone and I am left with $\pi$ amplitude instead.
Q: Are my calculations correct? Why I do not get my expected 1/2 of amplitude as magnitude?
Similar:

A similar question was asked here, but his calculations were not as analytical as mine and no one provided a real answer (to my understanding).
Here is
This guy here and here looks like both of their calculations reached the result I was expecting but they don't provide analytical calculations and I don't know how they got there.
These non-analytical calculations give out a magnitude of $j\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.
In this website they show analytical calculations until they reach the magnitude but it has a value of $\pi$, not $\frac{1}{2}$.

So I just keep on finding many similar results, but not the one that I expect + analytical calculation of how to get there.

Using your definition of Fourier transform one has $$\mathcal{F}t\sin(2, \pi, 60, t+\phi_0)=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(2, \pi, 60, t+\phi_0),  e^{-i \omega t} , dt=i \pi e^{-i \phi_0} \delta (\omega+120 \pi)-i \pi e^{i \phi_0} \delta (\omega-120 \pi)$$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function which is undefined at $x=0$, so the constants preceding the two Dirac delta terms are really the magnitudes of interest.

The related inverse Fourier transform is $$\mathcal{F}{\omega}^{-1}\lefti \pi e^{-i \phi_0} \delta(\omega+120 \pi)-i \pi e^{i \phi_0} \delta(\omega-120 \pi)\right\=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(i \pi e^{-i \phi_0} \delta (\omega+120 \pi)-i \pi e^{i \phi_0} \delta(\omega-120 \pi )\right)  e^{i t \omega}, d\omega\=\frac{1}{2} i \left(e^{-i (\phi_0+120 \pi t)}-e^{i (\phi_0+120 \pi t)}\right)=\sin(2, \pi, 60, t+\phi_0).$$
